# Bootstrap 4 radio buttons different colors on different computers

Tags: radio-button, bootstrap-4

For some reason bootstrap 4 radio buttons are blue on my Mac "this is what I want"
[on Mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alaiV.png)

But on my work pc they are black and white, why?
[work pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fqzN.png)

Comment: Different browser or same web browser? Where's the code? Asking a programming question without showing the code is like asking someone to fix the car from a picture.

Comment: Not a programming question, No code is needed, if you look at the bootstrap 4 page on a Mac and then on a work pc the colors of the radio button are different. Just wondering why. I added pics above.

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your HTML contains regular `<input type="radio">` code without any additional CSS styling. By this, the style of the radio buttons will be inherited from the browser and OS defined style (which is a normal behavior).